# Изменение шрифта у всех элементов в Delphi

Tags: delphi, шрифты

Как изменить шрифт у всех элементов элементов, у которых есть свойство Font?

Answer (score 5):

У всех наследников от `TWinControl` свойство `Font` может наследоваться от родительского контейнера. За это отвечает свойство `ParentFont`. Поэтому, если изменить `Font` у формы, он также изменится у всех вложенных в эту форму элементов с `ParentFont = True` (и дальше по каскаду от контейнера к содержимому).

**UPD:** Перебор всех компонентов формы с фильтром тех классов, в которых нужно менять шрифт:

```
for i := 0 to Form1.Components - 1 do
begin
  if Form1.Components[i] is TButton then
    TButton(Form1.Components[i]).Font := MyFont
  else
  if Form1.Components[i] is TLabel then
    TLabel(Form1.Components[i]).Font := MyFont
  else
  // ... и так далее ...
end;
```

Comment: Мне это не подходит, потому что  я наоборот это свойство отключил, так как мне оно мешает основной программе!

Comment: Непойму, зачем его отключаться если возникает прямая необходимость ним пользоваться?

Из велосипедов, могу предложить делать рекурсивный спуск по всем вложенным контейнерам. Или обычный линейный цикл по всем компонентам формы.

Comment: Обновил ответ исходником который пройдется по всем компонентам формы нужных типов

Answer (score 1):

```
for i := 0 to Form1.ControlCount - 1 do
    case Form1.Controls[i].ClassName of
        "TLabel", "TButton" { ... типы имеющие свойство font }:
            (TLabel)(Form1.Controls[i]).Font = NewFont;
        { может быть некоторые элементы также нужно рекурсивно перебирать }    
    end;
```

примерно так, с перебором всех элементов управления. Могу допускать синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Вариант для частного случая, когда все элементы располагаются на верхнем уровне форме. То есть, нет вложенных контейнеров. Например: если TButton будет лежать в TPanel, а тот в свою очередь на форме, то  TPanel попадет в цикл, а TButton - нет.

Comment: У меня почему-то ошибка! Компилятор ставит курсор на
    of

Comment: Вложенные контейнеры рекурсией перебрать. Не знаю как на `Delphi`, в `VBA` помню так делал, там в `controls` формы перебираются все элементы, в том числе и вложенных контейнеров.

Comment: Я чайник, и не понимаю как это!

Comment: Что не понимаете? Что такое рекурсия или что такое `Controls`?  
Запятую исправил.

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, в 3-й строке после `"TButton"` убери лишнюю запятую.

@ildar, да. Или пройтись по коллекции `Form.Components` c проверкой на типы элемента.

Answer (score 1):

для Delphi это будет выглядеть так:

```
type
  TMyControl = class(TControl)
  public
    property Font;
  end;
```

```
procedure SetFontByComponent(comp: TComponent; font: string);
var
     i: Integer;
  ctrl: TControl;
begin
  for i := 0 to comp.ComponentCount-1 do
    if comp.Components[i] is TControl then
      (TMyControl(comp.Components[i])).Font.Name := font;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetFontByComponent(self, 'Verdana');
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Я вот так решаю эту проблему в C++ Builder, работает в том числе для TLabel и пр., включая все дочерние объекты:

1. Создаем свой класс для получения публичного доступа к свойству Font

```
    class TMyControl: public TControl
    {
      public:
        __property Font;
    };
```

2. Далее перебором ставим шрифт всем компонентам, кроме верхнего меню

```
      AnsiString Name("Verdana");
      for (int i=0; iComponentCount; ++i)
      {
        TControl* ctrl = dynamic_cast<TControl*>(this->Components[i]);
        if (NULL == ctrl) continue;
        ((TMyControl*)ctrl)->Font->Name = Name;
      };
```

Comment: Вопрос про Делфи. При чем тут С++?

Comment: я опубликовал обе версии - и для Delphi и для C++ Builder. Потому что система одна и та же, разный только язык и очень часто разработчики Delphi ищут что-то, но находят только на с++ и вынуждены это переводить в паскаль и наоборот. Для новичков это бывает непросто, поэтому и выложил сразу оба варианта, искать могут и Delphi-разработчики и C++ Builder - разработчики. Вы же не спрашиваете почему на msdn несколько примеров одного и того же кода для одной платформы на разных языках? или спрашиваете?

Comment: p.s: а еще потому, что сам пишу исключительно на c++ и сходу написал ответ сначала на с++ (это всяко лучше, чем не дать никакого), но потом потратил немного времени и подготовил еще вариант на паскале. Код протестирован и там и там.

Comment: Делфовый вариант я плюсанул. Но давайте не будем превращать ответы в галлерею языков, а то придется еще на 15-20 языках написать. В вопросе четко указано - Delphi.

Comment: а давайте без давайте. Вы свое мнение своим минусом и плюсом высказали, я высказал своё - кодом. Поскольку сам неоднократно ранее сталкивался с подобными трудностями, то считаю свою позицию более верной. За сим весь флуд предлагаю закрыть и заняться делом